# How to find the particular text stored in the file "data.txt" and it occurs only once

Tags: linux, search

The line I seek is stored in the file data.txt and is the only line of text that occurs only once.

How do I go about finding that particular line using linux?

Comment: Could you please give an example of what the text page looks like? Just replace the password with some `dummy text` if you will as well please.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that there is only one line of text in data.txt? Then you just do `cat data.txt`.

Comment: @use1565960 - Why is that password not encrypted? Also why do you wish to have anothers password?

Comment: you.. playing over the wire? :P tnx

Answer (score 39):

This is a little bit old, but I think you are looking for this...

```
cat data.txt | sort | uniq -u
```

This will show the unique values that only occur once in the file. I assume you are familiar with "over the wire" if you are asking?? If so, this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Was wondering why i had to use `sort`... read `uniq`'s manual again and found out it compares to adjacent lines... thats why, thank you! Oh, and `sort -u` didn't work out, had to use the first command.

Comment: No need for the `cat` here!

Comment: `sort data.txt | uniq -u` to avoid the useless use of `cat`.

Answer (score 19):

To provide some context (I need more rep to comment) this is [a question that features in an online "wargame" called Bandit](http://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/bandit9.html) that involves using the command line to discover passwords on an online Linux server to advance up the levels.

For those who would like to see data.txt in full I've [Pastebin'd it here](http://pastebin.com/wGdtUyi2) however it looks like this:

```
NN4e37KW2tkIb3dC9ZHyOPdq1FqZwq9h
jpEYciZvDIs6MLPhYoOGWQHNIoQZzE5q
3rpovhi1CyT7RUTunW30goGek5Q5Fu66
JOaWd4uAPii4Jc19AP2McmBNRzBYDAkO
JOaWd4uAPii4Jc19AP2McmBNRzBYDAkO
9WV67QT4uZZK7JHwmOH0jnhurJMwoGZU
a2GjmWtTe3tTM0ARl7TQwraPGXgfkH4f
7yJ8imXc7NNiovDuAl1ZC6xb0O0mMBx1
UsvVyFSfZZWbi6wgC7dAFyFuR6jQQUhR
FcOJhZkHlnwqcD8QbvjRyn886rCrnWZ7
E3ugYDa6Wh2y8C8xQev7vOS8O3OgG1Hw
E3ugYDa6Wh2y8C8xQev7vOS8O3OgG1Hw
ME7nnzbId4W3dajsl6Xtviyl5uhmMenv
J5lN3Qe4s7ktiwvcCj9ZHWrAJcUWEhUq
aouHvjzagN8QT2BCMB6e9rlN4ffqZ0Qq
ZRF5dlSuwuVV9TLhHKvPvRDrQ2L5ODfD
9ZjR3NTHue4YR6n4DgG5e0qMQcJjTaiM
QT8Bw9ofH4x3MeRvYAVbYvV1e1zq3Xim
i6A6TL6nqvjCAPvOdXZWjlYgyvqxmB7k
tx7tQ6kgeJnC446CHbiJY7fyRwrwuhrs
```

One way to do it is to use:

```
sort data.txt | uniq -u
```

The `sort` command is like cat in that it displays the contents of the file however it sorts the file [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) by lines (it reorders them alphabetically so that matching ones are together).

The `|` is a pipe that redirects the output from one command into another.

The `uniq` command reports or omits repeated lines and by passing it the `-u` argument we tell it to report only unique lines.

Used together like this, the command will sort data.txt lexicographically by each line, find the unique line and print it back in the terminal for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
sort -u data.txt | while read line; do if [ $(grep -c $line data.txt) == 1 ] ;then echo $line; fi; done
```

was mine solution, until I saw here easy one:

```
sort data.txt | uniq -u
```

Answer (score 1):

Add more information to you post. 
How `data.txt` look like?
Like this:

```
11111111
11111111
pass1111
11111111
```

Or like this

```
afawfdgd
password
somethin
gelse...
```

And, do you know the password is in file or you search for not repeat string.

If you know password, use something like this

`cat data.txt | grep 'password'`

If you don`t know the password and this password is only unique line in file you must create a script. 
For example in Python

```
file = open("data.txt","r")
f = file.read()
for line in f: 
   if 'pass' in line:
        print pass
```

Of course replace pass with something else. 
For example some slice from line.

Answer (score 1):

```
sort data.txt | uniq -c | grep 1\ ?*
```

and it will print the only text that occurs only one time
do not forget to put space after the backslash

Answer (score 1):

And one with only one tool in use, **awk**:

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a){if(a[i] == 1){print i} }}' data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sort data.txt | uniq -c | grep 1
```

you will find only one that accures one time

Comment: `sort data.txt | uniq -c | grep -w 1` would be more precise